# How to permanently delete a row from table view in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I tried to delete the rows by using the delete code but the row reappear everytime. I want to permanently delete any particular row.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
var countries = ["India","Canada", "USA","Russia","Dubai"]
   
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return countries.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

//to enable delete action by swiping left
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        countries.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var userTxt: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    let obj = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userKey") as? String
    if let userName = obj {
        userTxt.text = userName
    }
    
}


@IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //we use this to save data
    UserDefaults.standard.set(userTxt.text, forKey: "userKey")
}

    @IBAction func deletePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "userKey")
    }
}
```

**[image: my code]**

Comment: In the code the swipe action is implemented to delete the row. But as the data source array `countries` is hard-coded the row is deleted only temporarily. To remove t permanently you have to save the modified data source array. And replace `tableView.reloadData()` with `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)` to remove the row animated

Answer (score 3):

You have to save the modified array of countries to persist the changes you have made to it. Here's what you need to do:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    //...
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            countries.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(countries, forKey: "countries")
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    //...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "countries") as? [String] {
            countries = array
        } else {
            countries = ["India","Canada", "USA","Russia","Dubai"]
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of delete does not persist the changes you make from delete as it uses a variable that’s initialized every time with data you hardcoded, hence array restores its elements to ones you specified every time you check back. So instead of hard coding values to an array to fill your tableView, consider using a persistent storage like a database or UserDefaults.